# PySimpleGUI appends Plots in Canvas

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, pysimplegui

I have the issue that if I try to update a canvas in PySimpleGUI the application instead appends the new plot below the old one. Trigering the 'Generate Plot' from the code below leads to the output at the bottom. Instead of Appending the plot I expected it to replace it.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

def draw_figure(canvas, figure):
   figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, canvas)
   figure_canvas_agg.draw()
   figure_canvas_agg.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both')
   return figure_canvas_agg

# Define the layout of the GUI
layout = [
    [sg.Button('Generate Plot')],
    [sg.Canvas(size=(100, 100),key='canvas')],
    [sg.Button('Exit')]
]

window = sg.Window('Time Series Plot', layout, finalize=True)

# Event loop
while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    x = np.linspace(1, 50)
    y = np.random.randn(50)

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break

    if event in ['Generate Plot']:
        fig, ax =plt.subplots()
        # Create a time series plot
        ax.plot(x, y)
        # Embed the Matplotlib plot into the PySimpleGUI window
        draw_figure(window['canvas'].TKCanvas, fig)            

# Close the window
window.close()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will create a new canvas under Canvas element when each time you call `FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, canvas)`, and they will be packed from top to bottom, not overlapped.

Call `figure_canvas_agg.draw()` if you just want to update the figure.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def draw_figure(canvas, figure):
   figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, canvas)
   figure_canvas_agg.draw()
   figure_canvas_agg.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both')
   return figure_canvas_agg

layout = [
    [sg.Button('Generate Plot')],
    [sg.Canvas(size=(100, 100),key='canvas')],
    [sg.Button('Exit')]
]

window = sg.Window('Time Series Plot', layout, finalize=True)

fig, figure_canvas_agg = None, None

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break

    if event == 'Generate Plot':

        if fig is None:
            fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        else:
            ax.cla()

        x = np.linspace(1, 50)
        y = np.random.randn(50)

        ax.plot(x, y)

        if figure_canvas_agg is None:
            figure_canvas_agg = draw_figure(window['canvas'].TKCanvas, fig)
        else:
            figure_canvas_agg.draw()

        window.refresh()
        window.move_to_center()

window.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are creating new canvas everytime you call `FigureCanvasTkAgg`. Create the canvas at the beginning like this.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

def draw_figure(figure_canvas_agg, figure):
   
   figure_canvas_agg.draw()
   figure_canvas_agg.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both')
   return figure_canvas_agg

# Define the layout of the GUI
layout = [
    [sg.Button('Generate Plot')],
    [sg.Canvas(size=(100, 100),key='canvas')],
    [sg.Button('Exit')]
]

window = sg.Window('Time Series Plot', layout, finalize=True)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, window['canvas'].TKCanvas)
# Event loop
while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    x = np.linspace(1, 50)
    y = np.random.randn(50)

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break

    if event in ['Generate Plot']:
        
        # Create a time series plot
        ax.plot(x, y)
        # Embed the Matplotlib plot into the PySimpleGUI window
        draw_figure(figure_canvas_agg, fig)            

# Close the window
window.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much but unfortunately, this does not work quite as I need it to - I would like tor replace the entire figure not just add an othe rtrace to the existing plot

Comment: @mhwh Then just clear it using `ax.clear()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to update the plot, then you should create the plot once and update the plot inside `draw_figure()`:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

def draw_figure(ax, fig_canvas):
   # clear current plot
   ax.cla()
   # draw the new plot
   x = np.linspace(1, 50)
   y = np.random.randn(50)
   ax.plot(x, y)
   fig_canvas.draw()
   fig_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both')

# Define the layout of the GUI
layout = [
    [sg.Button('Generate Plot')],
    [sg.Canvas(size=(100, 100),key='canvas')],
    [sg.Button('Exit')]
]

window = sg.Window('Time Series Plot', layout, finalize=True)

# create the figure and canvas
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, window["canvas"].TKCanvas)

# Event loop
while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break

    if event in ['Generate Plot']:
        draw_figure(ax, figure_canvas_agg)

# Close the window
window.close()
```